# jquery select event for combobox with one value

Tags: jquery, select

For a select combobox, is there a way to get an event when the user (re)selects the one and only value of a select combobox? `$(#sel).change(function(){})` only is called when I have at least 2 elements to select from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try the click event?
Like `$("#sel").click(function(){console.log('hi');})`